# Запрос в SQL с примерными данными

Tags: php, sql, запрос

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос к базе и получить максимально близкие или такие же данные.

есть таблица в которой поле users. К примеру:

```
id = 1; users = 1
id = 2; users = 5
id = 3; users = 10
id = 4; users = 13
id = 5; users = 15
id = 6; users = 100
id = 7; users = 19
id = 8; users = 25
id = 9; users = 30
id = 10; users = 35
```

Есть входные данные к примеру users = 20
Как мне получить 3-4 строки  которые ближе всего к этим данным. 
В данном случае (users 20):

```
id = 7; users = 19
id = 8; users = 25
id = 5; users = 15
id = 4; users = 13
```

Все что мне приходит в голову это сделать два запроса с разной сортировкой, но подозреваю что это будет не верно. Запрос на php в массив и потом обрабатываю циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одного запроса достаточно:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY ABS(users - 20)
LIMIT 4
```